# Бот вк для отправки фотографий

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

я пишу бота в вк который выступает в качестве путеводителя по городу. Но при написании столкнулся с проблемой. Бот не отправляет фотографии в личные сообщения. Бот не видит тот файл что я ему передаю пишет что аргумент пропущен.

```
class VkUpload(object):

    __slots__ = ('vk',)

    def __init__(self, vk):
        if not isinstance(vk, (VkApi, VkApiMethod)):
            raise TypeError(
                'The arg should be VkApi or VkApiMethod instance'
            )

        if isinstance(vk, VkApiMethod):
            self.vk = vk
        else:
            self.vk = vk.get_api()

    @property
    def http(self):
        return self.vk._vk.http

    def photo_messages(self, photos):
        url  = self.vk.photos.getMessagesUploadServer()['upload_url']
        print(ur1)
        with FilesOpener(photos) as photo_files:
            response = self.http.post(ur1, files=photo_files)
        return self.vk.photos.saveMessagesPhoto(**response.json())

    class FilesOppener(object):
    def __init__(self,paths, key_format='file{}'):
        if not isinstance(paths, list):
            paths = [paths]
        self.paths = paths
        self.key_format = key_format
        self.opened_files =[]
    def __enter__(self):
        return self.opened_files()
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.close_files()
    def open_files(self):
        self.close_files()
        files = []

        for x, file in enumerate(self.paths):
            if hasattr(file, 'read'):
                f = file

                if hasattr(file, 'name'):
                    filename = file.name
                else:
                    filename = '.jpg'
            else:
                filename = filename
                f = open(filename, 'rb')
                self.opened_files.append(f)
            exit = filename.split('.')[-1]
            files.append(
                (self,key_format(x), ('file{}.{}'.format(x,ext), f)))
        return files
    def close_files(self):
        for f in self.opened_files:
            f.close()
            self.opened_files= []

    print("Server started")
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            if event.to_me:
                print('New message:')
                print(f'For me by: {event.user_id}', end='')
                VkUpload.photo_messages("Gitrl.jpg")#Проблема здесь
                bot = VkBot(event.user_id)
                write_msg(event.user_id, bot.new_message(event.text))


                print('Text: ', event.text)
```

Comment: Вы экземпляр класса не создали, попробуйте так: `VkUpload(vk).photo_messages("Gitrl.jpg")`, где `vk` – объект `VkApi` или `VkApiMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

Переменную назвали `url`:

```
url  = self.vk.photos.getMessagesUploadServer()['upload_url']
```

А в аргументы передаете `ur1`:

```
response = self.http.post(ur1, files=photo_files)
```

Ошибка в синтаксисе)